# XAMPP WIN 7 Cache Directory Isn't writeable

Tags: php, xampp

I get the following error message when i try to run some php code on a site I have built in XAMPP

> Error 0: Cache directory 'C:\xampp\htdocs\eve-charinfo/.pheal-cache/722091/n3Yeskd6U90NyJXG5m5O6p5Rid9NVKKfJBaSVx3j9S3xApfAiYhBBSabzZas7VCr/account/APIKeyInfo/' isn't writeable

"Pheal is a PHP library for accessing the EVE API, its basically a PHP port of EAAL it uses some metaprogramming foo to ensure it does not need changes when the EVE API is changed. it also contains a simple file cache that can respects the EVE APIs cache timers."

Comment: Probably a file permissions issue. Make sure the directory is writable by the web server.

Comment: Try a quick Google search for "Windows 7 directory permissions"...

Comment: I already changed all the permissions for that folder for all users, in an attempt to accommodate any and all possibilities, to full control. No dice, i thought perhaps you were referring to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your PHP code will be a line that looks like this ....

```
PhealConfig::getInstance()->cache = new PhealFileCache('/your/path/to/the/cache/');
```

- Make sure this is a valid windows directory.
- Check you have write access to the directory. If its in a webroot
  directory you probably dont.
- Make sure the full path starts and ends with a '/' character Use a *NIX like file
  path, not a DOS type i.e. use '/' as a directory separator
- Do not include the C: drive directive
- Probably best not to use a '.' in a windows file path but will likely
  still work

And of course, your best source of answers about pheal is the EvE online Technology forum.